# jekyll and sass cannot compile sass files

Tags: sass, gruntjs, jekyll, jekyll-bootstrap

i've just started a new jekyll project using [a Yeoman generator](https://github.com/robwierzbowski/generator-jekyllrb)
it's configured using sass ut i cannot make it work

i've only one file in the _sass folder which is main.scss which begin with

```
@charset "utf-8";
```

but when i launch grunt serve i get this :

```
Running "copy:stageCss" (copy) task
[D] Task source: /Users/alexandresagette/Development/jekyll-site/node_modules/grunt-contrib-copy/tasks/copy.js
Verifying property copy.stageCss exists in config...OK
Options: encoding="utf8", processContent=false, processContentExclude=[], mode=false


Done, without errors.


Execution Time (2015-04-11 16:12:10 UTC)
loading tasks  1.1s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 99%
copy:stageCss   8ms  ▇ 1%
Total 1.1s
    Warning: Error: Invalid CSS after "@charset "utf-8"": expected "{", was ";"
        on line 4 of app/_sass/main.scss
  Use --trace for backtrace. Use --force to continue.

    Aborted due to warnings.
```

gruntfile can be found here : https://github.com/robwierzbowski/generator-jekyllrb/blob/master/app/templates/Gruntfile.js

Can someone help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

I was running grunt serve tasks one by one and figured it out that it is actually the sass task which is bugy:

```
    grunt --trace sass:server
Running "clean:server" (clean) task
>> 1 path cleaned.

Running "jekyll:check" (jekyll) task
`jekyll doctor` was initiated.


Jekyll output:
Configuration file: /Users/alexandresagette/Development/jekyll-site/_config.yml
  Your test results are in. Everything looks fine.

Running "sass:server" (sass) task
NoMethodError: undefined method `ascii_only?' for nil:NilClass
  Use --trace for backtrace.
Warning: Exited with error code 1 Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.


Execution Time (2015-04-11 18:06:30 UTC)
loading tasks  967ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 17%
jekyll:check    4.2s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 74%
sass:server    473ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 8%
Total 5.6s
```